# Mysql split string (column) into new rows by delimiter

Tags: mysql, delimiter

I have the following string **156,12,99,12,14,17** sometimes this is longer and/ or shorter and involves letters and numbers e.g cc,21,366,ddd.

The ideal output would be 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG9c5.png):

[image: output]

I have this which gives me the number of delimits in the column:

```sql
select
LENGTH(a.column) - LENGTH(REPLACE(a.column, ',', '')) + 1 AS numberofdelimit
FROM <mydatabase>.<mytable> as a
where a.id = 4;
```

I also know that this code will give me the text at which delimit:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.column, ',', numbers.n)
```

I'm struggling to put it together to put the values into new rows.

Comment: There's no straight forward way to do this in `MySQL`. You may have to write `MySQL function` to do this. Is there any problem in your end to use such user defined `mysql functions`?

Comment: One option is to use something like [common_schema](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html), specifically, [split_token](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/split_token.html) and [get_num_tokens](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/get_num_tokens.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you remove the need for ID, you can do something like this:

```
create table `ids` (
   `id` int
);

create table `input` (
   str varchar(256)
);

insert into ids (`id`) values
   (1), (2), (3), (4), (10), (20), (30), (40);

insert into input (`str`) values ('1,2,10,30');
```

And then match like this

```
select
   *
from
   input inner join ids
      on concat(',',str,',') rlike concat(',', id, ',');
```

It does require you to have a table on a side, though.

But it might be a beginning.